# How to assign months to their numeric equivalents in Python / Pandas?

Tags: python, datetime, pandas

Currently, I'm using the following for loop based on an if condition for each month to assign months to their numeric equivalents. It seems to be quite efficient in terms of runtime, but is too manual and ugly for my preferences.

How could this be better executed? I imagine it's possible to improve on it by simplifying/condensing the multiple if conditions somehow, as well as by using some sort of translator that is made for date conversions? Each of which would be preferable?

```
#make numeric month

combined = combined.sort_values('month')
combined.index = range(len(combined))
combined['month_numeric'] = None

for i in combined['month'].unique():
    first = combined['month'].searchsorted(i, side='left')
    last = combined['month'].searchsorted(i, side='right')
    first_num = list(first)[0] #gives first instance
    last_num = list(last)[0] #gives last instance
    if i == 'January':
        combined['month_numeric'][first_num:last_num] = "01"
    elif i == 'February':
        combined['month_numeric'][first_num:last_num] = "02"
    elif i == 'March':
        combined['month_numeric'][first_num:last_num] = "03"
    elif i == 'April':
        combined['month_numeric'][first_num:last_num] = "04"
    elif i == 'May':
        combined['month_numeric'][first_num:last_num] = "05"
    elif i == 'June':
        combined['month_numeric'][first_num:last_num] = "06"
    elif i == 'July':
        combined['month_numeric'][first_num:last_num] = "07"
    elif i == 'August':
        combined['month_numeric'][first_num:last_num] = "08"
    elif i == 'September':
        combined['month_numeric'][first_num:last_num] = "09"
    elif i == 'October':
        combined['month_numeric'][first_num:last_num] = "10"
    elif i == 'November':
        combined['month_numeric'][first_num:last_num] = "11"
    elif i == 'December':
        combined['month_numeric'][first_num:last_num] = "12"
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`to_datetime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_datetime.html), then [`month`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.dt.month.html), convert to string and use [`zfill`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.zfill.html):

```
print (pd.to_datetime(df['month'], format='%B').dt.month.astype(str).str.zfill(2))
```

Sample:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({ 'month': ['January','February', 'December']})
print (df)
      month
0   January
1  February
2  December

print (pd.to_datetime(df['month'], format='%B').dt.month.astype(str).str.zfill(2))
0    01
1    02
2    12
Name: month, dtype: object
```

Another solution is [`map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.map.html) by dict `d`:

```
d = {'January':'01','February':'02','December':'12'}

print (df['month'].map(d))
0    01
1    02
2    12
Name: month, dtype: object
```

**Timings**:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({ 'month': ['January','February', 'December']})
print (df)
df = pd.concat([df]*1000).reset_index(drop=True)

print (pd.to_datetime(df['month'], format='%B').dt.month.astype(str).str.zfill(2))
print (df['month'].map({'January':'01','February':'02','December':'12'}))

In [200]: %timeit (pd.to_datetime(df['month'], format='%B').dt.month.astype(str).str.zfill(2))
100 loops, best of 3: 13.5 ms per loop

In [201]: %timeit (df['month'].map({'January':'01','February':'02','December':'12'}))
1000 loops, best of 3: 462 µs per loop
```

Comment: Since neither of these take advantage of the data being sorted, are they slower options that what I wrote?

Comment: I think sorting is not necessary.

Comment: So the question would be, in a large disorganized dataset, would my code, or one of these solutions likely to be fastest? Or is there reason to believe differences would be negligible?

Comment: I think map will be faster, give me a sec, I add timings.

Comment: Yes, second solution is faster, see timings in update answer.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a map:

```
month2int = {"January":1, "February":2, ...}
combined["month_numeric"] = combined["month"].map(month2int)
```

Comment: Sorry, see my second solution.